# Vertically Centering 2 stacked and nested divs

Tags: css, html, centering

Ok, so I have a set of divs that I would like to be stacked one on top of another nested inside of another div. I would like these two stacked inner divs to be vertically centered in the parent div, but for the life of me I cannot get them to center. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="inner"> 
    <div class="center"><text class="label">Input 1:</text><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="center"><text class="label">Input 2:</text><input type="text"></div>
</div>
<div id="select">
    <select id="selector" multiple>
        <option>Option A</option>
        <option>Option B</option>
        <option>Option C</option>
        <option>Option D</option>
        <option>Option E</option>
        <option>Option F</option>
        <option>Option G</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.center {
    padding: 2.5px 5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#select {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

And here is a running example:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwinterton/PYB73/)

I would like to get the two "Center" class divs (the green fields in the jsfiddle) centered vertically inside of the "inner" div (yellow in the example). I have tried everything that I can think of and everything that I could find. I have even tried putting everything inside of one div and making that div `display: table-cell;` but then the elements aren't centered horizontally.

So better said, I would like all three elements (the two inputs and the select) both horizontally and vertically centered on the page. How can I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT:

Ok so I guess I didn't explain myself well enough. I want the yellow div and the red div to be on the same horizontal plane, with the two green divs stacked vertically and vertically centered in the yellow div. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PYB73/18/) is an example of what I want. I did this by adding `padding-top: 40px;` to the .inner div. But I want to achieve this same result without needing to place a hard-coded number of pixels into the padding because I need this to be dynamic and stretch do different sizes and remain centered. Does that make sense? I hope that I did a better job at explaining myself this time. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Have you checked my answer? I gave you three different options and one of them accomplishes this already...

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I have checked your answer, and your first result does indeed answer my question. Thank you for your answer and your help. However, if I add a height to the entire wrapper div like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bwinterton/PYB73/19/) example, then the items are not vertically centered. The fields are only vertically centered in comparison to the select div. Is there not a way to make them center vertically despite any height modifications?

Comment: Something like this work? http://jsfiddle.net/PYB73/20/

Comment: Yes and no, That does definitely get them centered horizontally and vertically, but then the wrapper isn't centered horizontally on the page anymore. However, I did get that to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bwinterton/PYB73/23/), all that I had to do was add another outer wrapper and make it `display: table; width: 100%;` and it is now centered horizontally and vertically. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Of course :) If you could hit the up arrow on my answer that would be fantastic :)

Comment: Would love to, but I don't have enough rep yet. When I do I will be sure to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few options for you so let's break them all down separately:

Option One: [Yellow Be-Gone!](http://jsfiddle.net/PYB73/14/)

If you read this in the voice of Billy Mays, this could be the option for you! In this option, I have done a few things. First off, let's take a look at the code that was most impacted:

```
#inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

If you cannot notice the difference yet, I took out your "height" variable, so that the div will define its own height and effectively take out that yellow space in between. If this isn't your option, that's ok! There are more to come :)

Option Two: Mom said we can keep [Ol' Yeller](http://jsfiddle.net/PYB73/15/)

In a blast from the past, actually, 1957 to be more exact comes this option! In this example, we keep the yellow div and successfully put the inner div in the middle, and have shortened the green width to be only as long as the input is. Let's take a look at the altering code that does this:

```
#inner {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: yellow;
    display:table-cell;
}
.center {
    padding: 2.5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Starting with inner, you will notice that I have added display: table-cell, which enables the display of anything inside of that div to become somewhat similar to a table-cell. To find more information on this neat trick, the [Almanac](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/) can go more in-depth. I also added in that the text-align should be centered, not right. Aligning the text right, will cause anything inside of this div to align to the right, not just the text, so this is why we change it to be in the middle.

Finally, in center simply add a display of inline-block to top off creating this design, which allows for the div's green background color to stop once everything inside of the div has reached it's max length. I will explain more about this in the third option. Again, both of these methods can be found in the Almanac.

Option Three: [The Green Monster](http://jsfiddle.net/PYB73/17/)

Can you smell Fenway Park in this option? I know I can. This option is similar to option two, but it allows for the inside div to reach the maximum width allotted to it. How do we do this? Check this code out:

```
.center {
    padding: 2.5px 5px;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It is extremely similar to the code above, in fact, it is the exact same thing set aside from taking out the inline-block display.

Any of these three options should give you exactly what you are looking for. Something key to point out, be sure that both the light blue and yellow div are the same width, the example you have given us shows that both of these divs are not exactly the same width, so just make sure you catch yourself on that. If none of these are working for you, shoot me a comment and I can try my best to figure something else out for you :)

Good luck and remember to use the Almanac when you can :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use flexboxes for layouts nowadays.

If I understood you right, this might be a solution: [codepen.io/enjikaka/pen/BeHkD](http://codepen.io/enjikaka/pen/BeHkD)

Few things you should think of:

- Do not target IDs in the CSS (using #), it is slower than targeting classes.

  - Use classes instead of IDs in CSS for selecting elements.
- There is no `<text>` element in HTML5. (?!) Use `<label>` as tag for the input field.

  - Use: `<label for="inputOne">Input 1</label><input id="inputOne" type="text">`

    - Notice: *for*'s value is the *id* of the `<input>` being labeled.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you need but,

this is the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner"> 
        <div class="center"><text class="label">Input 1:</text><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="center"><text class="label">Input 2:</text><input type="text"></div>
                <div id="select">
        <select id="selector" multiple>
            <option>Option A</option>
            <option>Option B</option>
            <option>Option C</option>
            <option>Option D</option>
            <option>Option E</option>
            <option>Option F</option>
            <option>Option G</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.center {
    padding: 2.5px 5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:100px;
}

.center input{ width:100px; }
#select {
    width:100px;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

This will get it all centered. Adjust as needed.
edit** here is the jdFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/somdow/eh3UY/
if you want it a bit lower vertically you can add some tp margin or top padding to the wrapper. Hope this works for you. good luck and welcome to SO.